# How to create a UI in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have downloaded eclipse i'm trying to create a form in eclipse, where i can see the tools with texbox, button..etc in eclipse ?  please help me to get the toolkit. I used the toolkit in Visual Studio, is there any toolkit for eclipse? I'm using Eclipse Indigo, in vista system.

Comment: Are you trying to write an Eclipse UI, or are you trying to write a UI in some language using Eclipse?

Comment: I'm trying to create UI and use java code.

Comment: You can start with Java Swing.  Start at this Oracle tutorial.  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/

Comment: I think you need to read up more on what you are trying to do.  Are you writing an Eclipse RPC application?  A swing application?  A web application?  This makes a big difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For desktop apps (Swing or Eclipse SWT), there's WindowBuilder. It's one of the core features that is included in the Eclipse for Java Developers package you can download from www.eclipse.org. If you downloaded a different Eclipse package, use Help > Install New Software to install WindowBuilder into your Eclipse.

For web pages, the Eclipse for Java EE Developers package includes a Web Page Editor with source view and "design" view. Design View has a palette of components that you can drag and drop to construct a page.